# Is it possible to update table when module disable or delete?

Tags: setup

I have created custom module which replicates **Shopping cart price Rule** module.
Used flag to filter core shopping cart price grid as well as my custom module grid.

I can able to create add my custom shopping price rule which i will use for my later purpose. I will use '**salesrule_validator_process**' observer to stop this rule.

Now when i delete/disable module from magento admin or module config.xml to false my custom created shopping rule has been applied to shopping cart in front end cart page.

Kindly advice on this situation to update salerule table when my custom module disabled or deleted ?

Answer (score 3):

No. Pity but Magento 1.x has no mechanism to trigger action on module deletion/deactivation.

The possible solution would be to have another module which will observe deletion of your module and do cleanup work. However this is far from being called "solution".

There were also couple of community attempts of implementing uninstall procedure but none of them I would recommend.

Comment: But they should be mentioned: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MageTrashApp

Comment: This is what I meant by "community implementations".

Comment: I know :-) And I think it is not useable in production, but it may help and I think it is hard to find :-)

Comment: @tim http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21464/salerule-replication-module-apply-to-cart-even-after-module-deletion-or-disable refer this question

Comment: OK will take a look. What shall we do with this one?

Comment: @Tim i have given logic to avoid apply rule after deletion the custom module.Logic on check page will work or it will affect magento performance.Kindly advice.